# magneto 2 installtion error on composer install

Tags: installation, magento2, laminas-api-tools, magento2.4, laminas

While installing magento 2.4.4 i got an issue like

```
 Install of laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin failed

                                                                                                                                                  
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                              
  Failed to execute git checkout '73cfb63ddca9d6bfedad5e0a038f6d55063975a3' -- && git reset --hard '73cfb63ddca9d6bfedad5e0a038f6d55063975a3' --  
                                                                                                                                                  
  fatal: reference is not a tree: 73cfb63ddca9d6bfedad5e0a038f6d55063975a3
```

anybody faced this issue,or anyone give a suggestion to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run `composer update` and it sovle my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I managed to continue the 'composer install' command by executing 'composer require laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin'. It started installing the requested version defined in my composer.lock. So I don't understand what the problem is/was.